# why is the order of operations (for multiplications and division) giving different result?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, operator-theory

Firstly sorry if this is tagged incorrectly or blindly obvious but it is confusing me a lot and I am not sure what category it would fall under. I have a particularly scenario where I am using the following formula and have verified this in both excel and in a javascript function

```
p = ( 4 * y * (1 - y)) * (1 - y) *2
value = x / p ;
```

But the value is incorrect unless I do it in steps:

```
p1 = ( 4 * y * (1 - y));
p2 = (1 - y)
value = x / p1 * p2 *2
```

with the example values `x = 917.963654` & `y=0.12` I get the following in excel

[image]

Comment: Note that $x/p1\times p1\times p2\times 2$ is the same as $\frac{x}{p1}\times p1\times p2\times 2$

Comment: I see it how obvious it is now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel does ((X/p1) * p2 *2) in the later case and not X/(p1*p2*2)

Comment: but this seems incorrect to me. `(x/p1) * p2 *2` should be the same as `x / p1 *p2 *2`, no?

Comment: I see it now, so obvious now, thanks